# Upload generated picture with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, generated

I have a script to add band name + picture of band. This is my controller:

```
public function addBand()
{
    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/bands';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('picture')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error);
        $this->load->view('concerts/index');
    }

    else {

        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];

        $data = array(
            'bName' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'bPicture' => $file_name
        );

        $this->band_model->insertBand($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', "Groupe ajouté");
        redirect('');
    }
}
```

This controller work nice! So. Now i add Cropper plugin in jquery. I get the value of *"#imagebase64"* and he return me the good result. After, i put a code to create picture from this data64. He work nice to. Now i want to add this code with Codeigniter.. and its dont work:

```
public function addBand()
{
    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/bands';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $img64 = $this->input->post('imagebase64');
    $exploded = explode(',', $img64, 2);
    $encoded = $exploded[1];
    $decoded = base64_decode($encoded);
    $img_handler = imagecreatefromstring($decoded);
    $finalImg = imagepng($img_handler, "png.png");

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('picture')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error);
        $this->load->view('concerts/index');
    }

    else {

        $finalImg = $this->upload->data();
        $file_name = $finalImg['file_name'];

        $data = array(
            'bName' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'bPicture' => $file_name
        );

        $this->band_model->insertBand($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', "Groupe ajouté");
        redirect('');
    }
}
```

When i make var_dump of $finalImg juste before **"$finalImg= $this->upload->data();"** i have **"boolean: 1"** , when i make the var_dump juste after the **$file_name = $finalImg['file_name'];** i have:

```
'file_name' => string 'eca69e25e70c469e73a5bfa114c5a87d.png' (length=36)
  'file_type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
  'file_path' => string 'C:/wamp64/www/concerts/uploads/bands/' (length=37)
  'full_path' => string 'C:/wamp64/www/concerts/uploads/bands/eca69e25e70c469e73a5bfa114c5a87d.png' (length=73)
  'raw_name' => string 'eca69e25e70c469e73a5bfa114c5a87d' (length=32)
  'orig_name' => string 'Sans_titre-1.png' (length=16)
  'client_name' => string 'Sans titre-1.png' (length=16)
  'file_ext' => string '.png' (length=4)
  'file_size' => float 368.2
  'is_image' => boolean true
  'image_width' => int 784
  'image_height' => int 419
  'image_type' => string 'png' (length=3)
  'image_size_str' => string 'width="784" height="419"' (length=24)
```

So, how can i generated picture in PHP and upload this picture with codeigniter ? Thanks!

Comment: $this->upload->data(); returns all the details of file uploaded,

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error message from the upload library? Further, I don't think you even need the upload library as you are doing your own logic with base64. The library needs a *file* not a string! So you could save your base64 decoded image as a file and just use that.

Comment: Hello! I want codeigniter librairie to use the encrypt file, allowed file, and upload path :/

Comment: can you post base 64 code??

Comment: @SachinAghera To decrypt the picture ? Its on my post (2nd code)

Comment: 'bPicture' => $file_name['file_name']

Comment: it should be like this

Comment: Its ok for the send data, the problem is to save the picture data64 with codeigniter restriction

Comment: but what is actual error?